# Navigation vertical secondary menu does not show over the content (the content below has position:position-relative)

Tags: html, css, css-position

I am making a website for our voluntary  association. Still learning web development.

Secondary vertical menue in Navigation menu (for example in activities tab)   does not show over the content. I found that it was due to the content below which is possitioned as position:relative  (col3 class) when I remove this position:relative  the problems solves but I need to keep it as it is for later improvements, you can view the website in this link
http://slsaj.com/panduka/Contact.html

[this screen shot shows the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/92Np6.jpg)

actually I have the same problem in Home menue (it is also due to this postion issue coming from javascript and css I guess) hope I would be able to solve it too with the answer to this question

<

```
        <div class="body1">
            <div class="main">
        <!-- header -->
                <header>
                    <div class="headerbox">

                        <a href="" id="logo"></a>
                        <a href="" id="logo2"></a>
                    <nav>

                          <div class="brand">
                            <h1>xxxxx Assoication in Japan </h1>
                          </div>
                            <div id="main-nav3">
                            <ul id="menu">
                                <li  ><a href="" >Home<span class="drop-down"></span></a>
                                    <ul>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                                <li ><a>Activities<span class="drop-down"></span></a>
                                    <ul>
                                        <li ><a href="" target="_blank" id="events" >Events</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="tharanga.html"  id="events2" >Tharanga Magazine</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="Conference.html" >Research Conference</a></li>
                                  </ul>
                                </li>
                                <li ><a href="" > Committee<span class="drop-down"></span></a>
                                    <ul>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>

                                <li id="menu_active"><a  href="">Contact<span class="drop-down"></span></a>
                                    <ul>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                                    <li ><a href="" >About us<span class="drop-down"></span></a>
                                    <ul>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div> <!-- menu -->
                    </nav>

                    </div>
                </header>
        <!-- / header -->
        <!-- content -->
                <article id="content">
                    <div class="wrapper">
                        <div class="box1">
                            <div class="line1 wrapper">
                                <section class="col1">  
                                    <h2><strong>O</strong>ur<span> Details</span></h2>
                                    <strong class="address">
                                        President:<br>
                                        Telephone:<br>
                                        E-Mail:<br>
                                        Secretary:<br>
                                        E-Mail:<br> <br>
                                        Fb:
                                    </strong>
                                    Mr. xxxx<br>
                                    080<br>
                                    <a href="">xxxx[at]gmail.com</a> <br>
                                    Ms. xxxxx<br>
                                    <a href="">xxxx[at]gmail.com</a> <br> <br>
                                    <a href="" target="_blank">@xxxxxxxxx</a>
                                </section>
                                <section class="col2 pad_left1">  <!-- This is the cause for this problem ***** -->
                                    <h2 class="color2"><strong>S</strong>ubcribe to<span> email database</span></h2>
                                    <p class="pad_bot1">
                                        You can subcribe to out email database by filling the following form  <br>
                                        <a href=""_blank"  class="button2 color2">Subcribe !</a>

                                    </p>

                                </section>
                            </div>
                        </div>  
                    </div>

             <!-- This col2  position:relative is  the cause for this problem ***** -->
            .col2 {margin:0 6px;width:560px;position:relative}

            #main-nav3 {
             float: left;
              width: 700px;
              z-index: 30;

            }
            #main-nav3 ul {
               font-size:12px;
              list-style: none;
            }
            #main-nav3 ul li {
              float: left;

            }
            #main-nav3 ul li:first-child {
              border: none;
            }
            #main-nav3 ul li a {
              display: block;
              position: relative;
              width: auto;
              text-decoration: none;
              font-size:17.8px;
            }
            #main-nav3 ul li a span.drop-down {

            }
            #main-nav3 ul li:hover {
              background: pink;

            }
            #main-nav3 ul li ul {
              display: none;
            }
            #main-nav3 ul li:hover ul {
              background: brown;
              display: block;
              position: absolute;
            }
            #main-nav3 ul li ul li {
              float: none;
              display: block;
              border-left: none;
              position: relative; z-index:10;
            }
            #main-nav3 ul li ul li a {
              width: auto;
              border-top: dotted 1px #7dad16;
              color: yellow;
```

Answer (score 0):

In the .headerbox css class, opacity: 0.9; is causing the issue. comment that out.
also in #main-nav3 ul li ul {...}  add z-index:10; which will fix the dropdown menu issue.